# How to show a dialog to confirm that the user wishes to exit an activity?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, onbackpressed

Am using below onBackpress method but this not working , am still click to back button repentantly came the same activity not exit current activity please solve my problem .

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Your Dialog Code is here.

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        ProfileActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                        finish();
                    }
                }).create().show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.setCancelable(false)` with `AlertDialog`,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Your Dialog Code is here.

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    ProfileActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                    finish();
                }
            }).create().show();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, its same issue just current page refresh only.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ProfileActivity.super.onBackPressed();` it will work.

Comment: You could also add `.setCancelable(false)` if you don't want to close the `AlertDialog` with back button if it's opened.

Answer (score 0):

remove this `ProfileActivity.super.onBackPressed();`

add

```
.setCancelable(false)
```

Comment: Sorry , same problem just refresh the current page

Comment: You are doing something wrong then because its working fine here i run the code and test it.

Comment: What i do , Am develop two app but same issue onBackpressed method , Anything android studio updating problem..?

Comment: No there is no issue with the android studio. lets come on chat

Comment: OK, Now What i do please help me. can you tell any solution...?

Comment: Once Uninstall the app, again install first time only onBackPressed method working after not working the  onBackPressed . this is the problem.